# Why Dask.dataframe.set_index doesn't recognize a combined column as single column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask

I got a csv file which date and time columns are separated. I tried to combine them and then set them as an index with `drop=false`. However I got an error told me Dask doesn't support multi-index.

The data look like this

```
Date[G]     Time[G]     #RIC   Price  Volume Tage
2014-08-29 15:09:38.408 VCTX.L 1726.0 72.0   T80
2014-08-29 15:09:38.408 VCTX.L 1726.0 114.0  T200
2014-08-29 15:09:38.408 VCTX.L 1726.0 72.0   T80
2014-08-29 15:11:30.608 VCTX.L 1725.2 500.0  T500
2014-08-29 15:14:45.905 VCTX.L 1727.0 211.0  T300
2014-08-29 15:14:45.905 VCTX.L 1727.0 82.0   T90
2014-08-29 15:14:45.905 VCTX.L 1727.0 135.0  T200
```

I combined `Date[G]` and `Time[G]` columns when I read the csv use `parse_dates=[['Date[G]','Time[G]']]` which return a single colum named `'Date[G]_Time[G]'`. And then I use`df.set_index(['Date[G]_Time[G]'], drop=False)`to set the index with the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CleanDataVR7.py", line 89, in <module>
    df.set_index(['Date[G]_Time[G]'], drop=False)
  File "/share/apps/anaconda/3/5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 2467, in set_index
    divisions=divisions, **kwargs)
  File "/share/apps/anaconda/3/5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py", line 39, in set_index
    "Indexes must be single columns only." % str(index))
NotImplementedError: Dask dataframe does not yet support multi-indexes.
You tried to index with this index: ['Date[G]_Time[G]']
Indexes must be single columns only.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this might be a case of simple syntax: drop the list square brackets, to make

```
df.set_index('Date[G]_Time[G]', drop=False)
```